# Invalid syntax - Glob image directory scan for carousel

Tags: php, syntax, foreach, carousel, glob

I have the following syntax error with this code:

Warning: `natcasesort()` expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in *Website*/assets/country-gallery-js.php on line 14

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in *Website*/assets/country-gallery-js.php on line 15

```
    <?php $thumbs = glob("img/thumb/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE); ?>
    <?php
    if(count($thumbs)) {
      natcasesort($thumbs);
      foreach($thumbs as $thumb) {?>
            <li class="item">
              <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/large/<?php echo basename($thumb) ?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" class="img-circle" width="100%" alt="" />
              </a>
          </li>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else {
      echo "Sorry, no images to display!";
    }
    ?>
```

I am unsure as to why. The code scans a folder for images to display as a carousel. It scans a thumbnail and large image folder for **lightbox**. When images are in the folder, it works like a treat.. when the folder is empty it should echo the 'else' text code. Instead it displays this syntax.

Can anyone help me figure this one out and stop the syntax from appearing?

Comment: So even though the directory is empty $thumbs must be returning something.  var_dump($thumbs);

Comment: Yes, it is returning the above error pointing to the lines of:          natcasesort($thumbs); 
         foreach($thumbs as $thumb) {

Comment: Write out $thumbs before you get to natecasesort. in fact use exit; and just vardump($thumbs);

Comment: $thumbs return "bool(false)" which when counted equals 1.  Do what Nahne says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use is_array instead of count 
<?php $thumbs = glob("img/thumb/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE); ?>
<?php
if (is_array($thumbs)) {
    natcasesort($thumbs);
    foreach ($thumbs as $thumb) {
        ?>
        <li class="item">
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/large/<?php echo basename($thumb) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" class="img-circle" width="100%" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>

        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry, no images to display!";
}
?>
```

Comment: That's got it! Thanks a lot, I understand the problem now

Answer (score 0):

I believe using the braces syntax:

```
glob("img/thumb/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

wont work, this probably will:

```
glob("img/thumb/*.jpg,img/thumb/*.png,img/thumb/*.gif", GLOB_BRACE);
```

The first step to what you ought to do to check where the problem lies is check what kind of value the variable $thumbs holds. This would have told you that the problem probably lies within the glob function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, nothing changed. The problem was an array would have been better

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the part of when the images are in the folder, my bad